# most frequently used queries mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'am a little confused about how to find most frequently used queries in mysql. I'm looking this query because I want use memcache tool in php application. Is really only way to find them is log every query to log file and after work on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [General Query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html) Log is only the solution to do that. I couldn't find any other way. If the purpose is to optimize slow queries then you can use [Slow Query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/slow-query-log.html) Log to find the slowest queries.

Comment: I couldn't find too, but maybe exists another solution.